# Windows function ChoosePixelFormat returns ERR_OLD_WIN_VERSION on windows 7

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I'm trying to teach myself the win32 API by making a window and attaching an OpenGL context to it.  In order to fetch the appropriate pixel format a call to ChoosePixelFormat must be made which should return a pixel format that the system supports and best meets my needs.  When I check for errors everything goes smoothly until this function is called which stops execution and logs error 1150-ERR_OLD_WIN_VERSION which is supposed to mean that my version of windows does not support this function.  This is obviously not the case and msdn confirms that this function runs on all versions of windows since windows 2000.  Right now I'm running windows 7 x64 on my desktop and I made sure my video driver and os were fully updated.  Lots of people seem to have had trouble with the pixel format functions but I have not found any with my problem so I decided to post here for help.  Here is my full code; I have not tested it on any machines other than my own.

WinMain.cpp  (the only non-default msvc lib this is linked with is opengl32.lib)

```
#include"Display.h"
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>

MSG message;
DWORD error;
int status;

LRESULT CALLBACK WndProc(HWND hWindow, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{   switch(message)
    {case WM_CREATE:
        return 0;
    case WM_DESTROY:
        PostQuitMessage(0);
        return 0;
    case WM_KEYDOWN:
        switch(wParam)
        {case VK_ESCAPE:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            return 0;}}
    return DefWindowProc(hWindow, message, wParam, lParam);}

int MainLoop(Display d)
{
    while((status = PeekMessage(&message, d.hWindow, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE)) != 0)
    {
        if (status == -1)
        {
            return -1;
        }
        DispatchMessage(&message);
    }
    return 0;
}

int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, LPSTR lpCmdLine, int nCmdShow)
{
    std::ofstream file("log.txt", std::ios::trunc);


    Display window("TEST", hInstance, WndProc, 50, 50, 50, 50, NULL, NULL);
    if(window.status == -1)
    {   error = GetLastError();
        file << error;
        return 1;}

    ShowWindow(window.hWindow, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
    EnableWindow(window.hWindow, true);
    MainLoop(window);

    return 0;
}
```

Display.h  (problem occurs in the class constructor)

```
#include <Windows.h>

class Display   
{public:
    Display(const char*, HINSTANCE, WNDPROC, int, int, int, int, DWORD, DWORD);
    ~Display();
    HWND hWindow;
    int status;
private:
    WNDCLASSEX data;
    HDC hDeviceContext;
    HGLRC hGLContext;
    PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR PFD;
    int x, y, width, height;};
Display::Display(const char* title, HINSTANCE InstanceHandle, WNDPROC WindowProcedure, int ScreenPositionX, int ScreenPositionY, int WindowWidth, int WindowHeight, DWORD StyleFlags, DWORD ExtendedStyleFlags)
{   data.cbSize = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
    data.style = CS_OWNDC;
    data.lpfnWndProc = WindowProcedure;
    data.cbClsExtra = 0;
    data.cbWndExtra = 0;
    data.hInstance = InstanceHandle;
    data.hIcon = NULL;
    data.hCursor = NULL;
    data.hbrBackground = NULL;
    data.lpszMenuName = NULL;
    data.lpszClassName = "WIN1"; 
    data.hIconSm = NULL;
    RegisterClassEx(&data);
    hWindow = CreateWindowEx(ExtendedStyleFlags, data.lpszClassName, title, StyleFlags | WS_CLIPSIBLINGS | WS_CLIPCHILDREN, x = ScreenPositionX, y = ScreenPositionY, width = WindowWidth, height = WindowHeight, NULL, NULL, InstanceHandle, NULL);
    PFD.nSize = sizeof(PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR);
    PFD.nVersion = 1;
    PFD.iPixelType = PFD_TYPE_RGBA;
    PFD.iLayerType = PFD_MAIN_PLANE;
    PFD.dwVisibleMask = 0;
    PFD.dwLayerMask = 0;
    PFD.dwDamageMask = 0;
    PFD.dwFlags = PFD_DRAW_TO_WINDOW | PFD_DOUBLEBUFFER | PFD_SUPPORT_OPENGL;
    PFD.cAuxBuffers = 0;
    PFD.bReserved = 0;
    PFD.cColorBits = 24;
    PFD.cAccumBits = 0;
    PFD.cDepthBits = 32;
    PFD.cStencilBits = 0;
    PFD.cAlphaBits = 0;
    PFD.cAccumAlphaBits = 0;
    PFD.cAlphaShift = 0;
    PFD.cBlueBits = 0;
    PFD.cAccumBlueBits = 0;
    PFD.cBlueShift = 0;
    PFD.cGreenBits = 0;
    PFD.cAccumGreenBits = 0;
    PFD.cGreenShift = 0;
    PFD.cRedBits = 0;
    PFD.cAccumRedBits = 0;
    PFD.cRedShift = 0;
    hDeviceContext = GetDC(hWindow);
    int pf = ChoosePixelFormat(hDeviceContext, &PFD); //throws error 1150, next three throw error 2000 because of this failing
    SetPixelFormat(hDeviceContext, pf, &PFD);
    hGLContext = wglCreateContext(hDeviceContext);
    wglMakeCurrent(hDeviceContext, hGLContext);
    if(GetLastError() != ERROR_SUCCESS)
        {status = -1;}
    else
        {status = 0;}
    return;}
Display::~Display()
{   wglMakeCurrent(NULL, NULL);
    wglDeleteContext(hGLContext);
    DestroyWindow(hWindow);
    UnregisterClass(data.lpszClassName, data.hInstance);}
```

Comment: When you say *"non-default msvc lib*" are you saying that you are linking against an OpenGL32.lib that is not part of the Windows SDK? Also, to make sure that your linker really links against a specific library you can specify the [/VERBOSE:LIB](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wdsk6as6.aspx) linker option to display which libraries are searched.

Comment: Are you saying `ChoosePixelFormat` is returning 1150?  If so, that's a success per the docs: `If the function succeeds, the return value is a pixel format index (one-based) that is the closest match to the given pixel format descriptor.`

Comment: @Ninja sorry for the poor choice of words.  The function returns a zero which indicates failure.  If GetLastError() is called just after it will return 1150

Comment: @IInspectable another poor choice of words on my part.  In linker settings Opengl32.lib is listed as a dependency.  I'm not having trouble with this I just included this in case someone else running the code had a problem with the 'wgl' functions not being defined

Comment: I think there should be a `default:` label in your `WndProc` function.

Answer (score 1):

After I have tried all mentioned solutions I still had the same problem with ERR_OLD_WIN_VERSION after ChoosePixelFormat. In my case the problem was about the graphics card driver:

The system I'm working on uses an EVGA card with a GTX 770 GPU and yesterday I installed driver version 331.65. After that I got the same problems as the questioner. Installing the **current Version 337.88** fixed the issue in my case. However ERR_OLD_WIN_VERSION seams to lead us in the wrong direction.

Answer (score 0):

In your `Display` constructor, it looks like you don't initialize the `hWindow` member before you use it.  That would be the value returned by `CreateWindowEx`.

Comment: How stupid of me.  This does not fix the error 1150 that I'm getting but is still helpful I guess.  I'ts interesting though that the call to GetDC(hWindow); did not trigger any errors when hWindow was left uninitialized

Comment: @user2297599: That's because `GetDC (NULL)` is a special-case that returns the device context of the "Desktop" window. Since uninitialized values often take on NULL in MSVC this is probably what was happening.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of testing the address of the `GetLastError` function, you should be calling it and testing its return value against `ERROR_SUCCESS`. I think this may be an oversight when you pasted the code, as you seem to be getting meaningful results from `GetLastError (...)`.

#### UPDATE:

You might want to try something like:

```
#ifndef WINVER
# define WINVER 0x0500
#endif
```

Before `#include <Windows.h>`

That tells it to include all of the fields in the data structures that are new in Windows NT 5.0 (Windows 2000). Many of these structures determine the version of Windows they are targeting by the `sizeof` your structure, which will vary depending on how you have WINVER defined.

Comment: I'd love to know why this answer was silently down-voted. In any case, you are testing the address of `GetLastError` instead of calling it, and the return value of your window proc is what `CreateWindow<Ex> (...)` uses to determine whether or not your window creation was successful, it expects a value of 0 for success, anything else denotes failure. At the very least, add a case for `WM_CREATE` and return 0.

Comment: I wondered about the drive-by down-vote too.  The point about `GetLastError` seems valid, but I'm not enough of a Windows programmer to be sure about the `WM_CREATE` issue.  Anyway, I'll bring you back up to 0.

Comment: I don't have enough reputation to vote so I don't really know who did that, but this is helpful information.  I'm going to update the code. Also it would be awesome if one of you could try out the code on your machine and tell me if you are getting a similar error in log.txt so I know there isn't something wrong with my version of windows.

Comment: @user2297599: I just remembered something about the pre-processor definition: `WINVER` that might be relevant in this situation... see my updated answer for more details.

Comment: Passing `WM_CREATE` to `DefWindowProc` is fine, it will return success and the window will be created.  There does however appear to be a `default:` label missing.

Comment: @BenVoigt: Thank you, I corrected the answer. I could have sworn `WM_CREATE` didn't play well with `DefWindowProc (...)`, I must be thinking of something else.

Comment: the WINVER thing didn't work. I'm going to dust off my old vista machine and try it out on there.  It's starting to look like this issue is quite specific to me.

Answer (score 0):

I was not able to boot up my older machine, but I did discover something when looking through the source code of [SDL](http://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php). It seems that they defined their own version of ChoosePixelFormat that loops through all available pixel formats using DescribePixelFormat and then compares them to the desired pixel format before choosing the best one.  Since this is the exact same definition of windows's ChoosePixelFormat I suspect they had a good reason to make their own.  Perhaps they knew it gave trouble in certain situations.  Unfortunately since Microsoft Developer support is a myth, and barely anyone seems to care, this is as good an answer as I'll get for now.  And since I've stopped caring too, this is probably the closest this question will ever get to an answer.  Thnaks to those of you who tried to help.